# General Solution for Cosine (negative angles)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

- $cos(2(x+\pi/3))=1/2$
- $2(x+\pi/3)=\pi/3$
- $x+\pi/3=\pi/6$
- $x+2\pi/6=\pi/6$
- $x=-\pi/6$
- $x=5\pi/6$ **(is this step correct)** ... ??
- $x = +/- \pi/6 +k\pi$ , $k$ is a subset of $Z$
- $x = +/- 5\pi/6 +k\pi$ , $k$ is a subset of $Z$

can someone please look over my working out, and correct me

Comment: @consfues, what is "negative angles" in title?

Comment: because it is negative pi/6 not simply pi/6

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos2\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)=\frac12=\cos\frac\pi3$$

$$\implies2\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)=2m\pi\pm\frac\pi3$$ where $m$ is any integer

$$\implies x+\frac\pi3=m\pi\pm\frac\pi6$$

$\displaystyle'+'\implies x+\frac\pi3=m\pi+\frac\pi6\iff x=m\pi-\frac\pi6$

etc.

Comment: so its +/- pi/6 + mpi ??

Comment: @confused, No. '-' implies $$x+\frac\pi3=m\pi-\frac\pi6\iff x=m\pi-\frac\pi2$$

Comment: i don't understand where pi/2 is coming from

Comment: @confused,  '-' implies $$x+\frac\pi3=m\pi-\frac\pi6\iff x=m\pi-\frac\pi6-\frac\pi3$$ $$\frac\pi6+\frac\pi3=?$$